# WCF returns 400 Bad Request when trying to upload

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, file-upload, stream

I have been at this for a while now and would really appreciate a second opinion on this. Can't seem to figure out why i'm getting a 400 Bad Request.

WCF Web Config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="FileTransferServicesBinding"
      transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom"
      sendTimeout="01:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
 maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
 maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="FileTransferServiceBehavior">

    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="FileTransferServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="PP.Live.WCFService.MobileClient">
    <endpoint name="MobileClientEndpoint" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FileTransferServicesBinding" contract="PP.Live.WCFService.LiveService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

And then the Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface LiveService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    UploadMedia UploadFile(System.IO.Stream fileData);


 }

[DataContract]
public class UploadMedia
{
    [DataMember]
    public UploadStatus Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public enum UploadStatus
{
    Success,
    Error
}
```

And the SVC:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MobileClient : LiveService
{

    public UploadMedia UploadFile(System.IO.Stream fileData)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Uploading File");
        UploadMedia uploadMedia = new UploadMedia();
        try
        {
            //byte[] imageBytes = StreamHelper.ReadToEnd(fileData);
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            fileData.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            memoryStream.Close();
            memoryStream.Dispose();

            string token = StoreFile(imageBytes);

            fileData.Close();
            fileData.Dispose();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            {
                uploadMedia.Message = token;
                uploadMedia.Status = UploadStatus.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                uploadMedia.Message = "No Token";
                uploadMedia.Status = UploadStatus.Error;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            uploadMedia.Message = ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;
            uploadMedia.Status = UploadStatus.Error;

        }

        return uploadMedia;
    }
```

Thank you so much for looking over this for me.

Comment: Please post your correct `web.config`.  The one you have posted is incomplete. For example, you have an open `system.serviceModel` tag, but not close.

Comment: What does your client's .config file look like?

Answer (score 1):

Change the size of the message in basicHTTPBinding, it might be because of file size is greater than the size can be handled by WCF.

refer to below link -

http://forums.asp.net/t/1299246.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable [**Tracing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service to see why you are getting a 400 BadRequest.

In order to access your service in a RESTful way you need to have your binding as webHttpBinding where as in your config you are using basicHttpBinding

Also make sure that you have used the KnowType attribute for your service to identify your UploadMedia and UploadStatus objects for deserialization.